# Incomprehensible "De mesure"

Tags: lexique

"Les chrétiens des pays européens, attachés aux idéaux évangéliques de mesure dans l’attachement aux biens matériels et de don de soi dans le service du prochain, s’inscrivent de moins en moins dans le tableau idéal du monde de la consommation", constate le chef de l’Église orthodoxe russe.

What does "de mesure dans" mean in this context? It all doesn't seem very logical. If it weren't for this part: "de mesure... du prochain" I would have no trouble getting it.

Source: https://fr.sputniknews.com/20211026/le-capitalisme-moderne-est-incapable-de-produire-des-humains-selon-le-patriarche-kirill-1052334429.html

Comment: Cela a été transcrit et traduit du Russe. Je ne pense pas que ce monsieur parle français.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Mesure*** is related to ***idéaux***. In *idéaux évangéliques de mesure*, the noun ***mesure*** means ***modération***, i.e. the ideal attitude of being moderate, the opposite of being excessive.

Here is how to parse this sentence:

> *Les chrétiens des pays européens,* (European christians)
> (
>     *attachés aux idéaux évangéliques*  (loyal to the values of the gospel)
>     (
>       (
>           *1.   de mesure dans l’attachement aux biens matériels*  (of moderation in the desire for material things)
>       )
>              [ *et* ]  [and]
>       (
>            *2.  de don de soi dans le service du prochain*  (of altruism)
>       )
>     )
> )
> *s’inscrivent de moins en moins dans le tableau idéal du monde de la consommation.*  (less and less fit the image of the ideal consumerist world.)

Removing any part enclosed with parenthesis can be done without breaking the sentence.

Executive summary: European christians aren't greedy and selfish so do not fit well a consumerist economy.

---

Here is the [original text in Russian](http://www.patriarchia.ru/db/text/5856096.html) (patriarchia.ru):

> христиане западных стран в своем следовании евангельским идеалам умеренности в материальных благах и жертвенному служению ближним все менее вписываются в идеальную картину мира потребления.

It was first published in the [French edition of the Forbes magazine](https://www.forbes.fr/business/comment-sa-saintete-le-patriarche-cyril-de-moscou-et-de-toutes-les-russies-considere-t-il-la-position-de-leglise-orthodoxe-en-matiere-deconomie/).

DeepL translates the Russian text to:

> Les chrétiens des pays occidentaux, dans leur adhésion aux idéaux évangéliques de modération dans les biens matériels et de service sacrificiel aux autres, correspondent de moins en moins à l'image idéale du monde de la consommation.

> Christians in Western countries, in their adherence to the evangelical ideals of moderation in material goods and sacrificial service to others, fit less and less into the ideal picture of the consumer world.

Google translate:

> Les chrétiens des pays occidentaux dans leur adhésion aux idéaux évangéliques de modération des richesses matérielles et de service sacrificiel aux autres s'inscrivent de moins en moins dans l'image idéale du monde de la consommation.

> Christians of Western countries in their adherence to the evangelical ideals of moderation in material wealth and sacrificial service to others are less and less fit into the ideal picture of the world of consumption.

The main translation issue of the Sputniknews (Forbes) text is the usage of ***pays européens*** while the Russian refers to "Western countries" that should probably have been translated to *pays occidentaux*.

---

Note: As already stated, ***mesure*** is here a formal synonymous of ***modération***.

TLFi [Mesure](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mesure)

> **B.- 2. b)** Modération, retenue (dans le comportement, dans le mode de vie, dans les goûts esthétiques). Synonyme *discrétion, réserve. Le goût, le sens de la mesure; perdre toute mesure. Mais c'est surtout dans ce qui nous reste des arts plastiques des anciens que cette qualité de goût et de mesure parfaite se trouve au plus haut point de perfection* (Delacroix, *Journal*, 1857, p.57). *Il se piquait de vivre avec mesure et raison* (Beauvoir, Mandarins, 1954, p.447)

The sequence ***de mesure dans*** is nevertheless common, e.g.:

> *Mais le représentant des caisses d'allocations familiales a rappelé que le Gouvernement demandait à maintes reprises au régime général de la sécurité sociale de marquer plus **de mesure dans** ses dépenses.*, Sénateur, *Journal officiel de la République française*, 1965.

> *Vous avez fait preuve **de mesure dans** votre expression, mais nous avons bien senti ce qu'il y avait derrière.* M. le Président, *Groupe de travail sur l'efficacité de la dépense publique et le contrôle parlementaire, Auditions*, 1999

<sub>PS: Corrections et améliorations de mon anglais sont les bienvenues.</sub>

Comment: OK, thank you, but how would you translate "attachés aux idéaux évangéliques de mesure dans l’attachement aux biens matériels et de don de soi dans le service du prochain"? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Answer updated with an explanation about how to read the sentence.

Comment: ***De** mesure **dans*** n'est pas reconnu par le Robert, ce qui fait que je n'ai pas du tout compris la phrase avant que tu ne l'expliques ! Pur jargon, usage de la francophonie éloignée ou traducteur humanoïde débutant, n'est pas la question, la réponse :   « … idéaux évangéliques ***modérés*** »

Comment: @Personne Ce ne sont pas les idéaux qui sont modérés, mais les idéaux qui prônent la modération. Je serais moins sévère que toi. Le texte français est certes complexe mais ne me semble pas vraiment critiquable. *Avoir de la mesure dans quelque chose* ne choque pas du tout. J'ai trouvé le texte original, si jamais un(e) russophone passe par là...

Comment: — « *Ce ne sont pas les idéaux qui sont modérés, mais les idéaux qui prônent la modération*. » — Est-ce que les idéaux totalitaires prônent la modération ? Quelle différence entre le texte de loi et son application attendue dans le contexte de la question ? || — *Avoir de **la** mesure dans quelque chose* ne choque pas du tout. — Moi non plus quand le *la* donne du sens. || Dans la question, y a-t-il un verbe qui reflète une action (et non un état) avant "de mesure dans" pour déterminer l'orientation du mot *mesurable* : « détermination d'une grandeur *vs* quantité mesurable » ?  ……

Comment: …… de plus, dans tes exemples, chaque fois, le *de* est rattaché au mot qui le précède. || — Bigre, plus la phrase est alambiquée plus elle doit être simple et claire quand on l'écoute, sans fausse note ou double sens non voulu :-)

Comment: @Personne Peut-être que la phrase est déjà alambiquée en russe et donc que la traduction est fidèle aussi à cette *alambiguïté* ;-)

Comment: C'est tout le problème du traducteur, mais comme DeepL « Les chrétiens des pays occidentaux, dans leur adhésion aux idéaux évangéliques *de modération dans* les biens matériels et de service sacrificiel aux autres, correspondent de moins en moins à l'image idéale du monde de la consommation. » donne une traduction semblable, il est plus que fort probable que la mise en mots des pensées russes se construise différemment. — +1 pour *alambiguïté* !

Answer (score -1):

> Les chrétiens des pays européens, attachés aux idéaux évangéliques de
> mesure dans l’attachement aux biens matériels et de don de soi dans le
> service du prochain, s’inscrivent de moins en moins dans le tableau
> idéal du monde de la consommation", constate le chef de l’Église
> orthodoxe russe.
>
> Christians in European countries, who are attached to the evangelical
> ideals of moderation with regard to material wealth and the giving of
> oneself in service to others are less and less part of the ideal
> picture of a consumerist world [or consumerism].

**OR heavier**: evangelical ideals of moderation in attachment to material wealth

biens are goods or assets, the meaning is wealth, here.

"de mesure dans" is pretty much nonsense, but, if one knows this type of context, the sentence works fine with "moderation, as in something measured.

The sentence is a transcription and translation from Russian, so, it didn't come out perfectly in French.

Comment: *De mesure dans* is very common, including with the meaning of the sentence, not sure why you believe it's nonsense.

Comment: Yes, de mesure, moderation.

Comment: Oui la formulation tout à fait correcte mais pas immédiatement claire à la lecture du fait des nombreux sens possibles de *mesure*. La compréhension serait plus immédiate avec *modération*. "Pretty much nonsense" est peut-être exagéré, quand même.